# Two different table values display in single datagridview C# .Net Windows Application

Tags: c#, .net, c#-3.0

> Table1 : Mani, Ram, Guna, Praveen, jai
>   Table2 : kumar, bharath, ashok, vikram, san.

Two different tables, I want display a output is single data gridview such as display First class and second class Two names display in one by one (Same column display I want) can you please some one help, what this solution?

I want output is:

First Class

> Mani
>   Ram
>  
>   Guna
>  
>   Praveen
>   jai

Second Class

> kumar
>  bharath
>  ashok
>  vikram
> san

Comment: Hi, try to use the bellow solution by adding an extra rows as "First Class" and "Second Class" to data table dt3.

Comment: SQL query: select name from table1 union select name from table2. So that you don't have to loop through data and merge multiple datatables in C# code.

Comment: UNION your selects and load grid. This is not that hard

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
           DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            dt1.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            dt1.Rows.Add(new string[] {"Mani"});
            dt1.Rows.Add(new string[] {"Ram"});
            dt1.Rows.Add(new string[] {"Guna"});
            dt1.Rows.Add(new string[] {"Praveen"});
            dt1.Rows.Add(new string[] {"Jai"});

            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
            dt2.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            dt2.Rows.Add(new string[] {"kumar"});
            dt2.Rows.Add(new string[] {"bharath"});
            dt2.Rows.Add(new string[] {"ashok"});
            dt2.Rows.Add(new string[] {"vikram"});
            dt2.Rows.Add(new string[] {"san"});

            DataTable dt3 = dt1.Copy();
            foreach (DataRow row in dt2.AsEnumerable())
            {
                dt3.Rows.Add(row.ItemArray);
            }
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt3;​
```